# how to save list of images in flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am creating a blog website using flask and I want each post to have multiple images. Uploading of multiple image is working but I can't display them.

I try to display it like this and it only gives me the last uploaded picture. Also when I print post.property_pictures I get only one file even though all uploaded images are saved in folder.

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='property_pictures/' + post.property_pictures)}}">
```

I tried to change type of the property_pictures column but unsuccessfully. How can I change it to accept list of files?

Here is my models.py:

```
class Posts(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=False)
    title = db.Column(db.String(124), nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    county = db.Column(db.String(124), nullable=False)
    quadrature = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    property_type = db.Column(db.String(124), nullable=False)
    property_pictures = db.Column(db.String(1000), default="default_property.png")

    def __init__(self, user_id, title, text, county, quadrature, price, property_type, property_pictures):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.title = title
        self.text = text
        self.county = county
        self.quadrature = quadrature
        self.price = price
        self.property_type = property_type
        self.property_pictures = property_pictures
```